# why loop is infinite

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to solve a problem where I have to find all the sub pairs which sum to zero.
In my solution when sum == 0, it goes into an infinite loop. What I am doing wrong here.

```
function sumZero(data) {
  let left = 0;
  let right = data.length - 1;
  let finalArray = [];
  while (left < right) {
    let sum = data[left] + data[right];
    if (sum === 0) {
      finalArray.push([data[left], data[right]]);
    } else if (sum > 0) {
      right--;
    } else {
      right++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: _"when sum == 0, it goes into infinite loop"_ - No. When `sum == 0` then the function (and the loop) will be terminated because of the `return ...`

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: If I remove return statements, then it goes into infinite. what could be the correct solution

Comment: I think you misunderstood what is happening. I do not believe this is because sum ===0 I think what is happening is that sum never = 0 or left is never more than right. Before I go on a full thing about how i think it can be solved. Please share what data you are inputting I think I see the main issue. I'll point out though that how you are getting 0 from ADDING needs to be checked as well.

Answer (score 1):

If sum==0, you push the items in finalArray, but you don't manage the left or right, thus it will be forever the same items and the same sum. Try to increase left (left++) if sum ==0

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue lies in here:

```
else if (sum > 0) {
  right--;
} else {
  right++;
}
```

You might either want to replace a `right` with a `left`. The reason why your are getting an infinite loop is when the sum < 0. The right will increment, thus, having the same behavior as the previous iteration and hence, the algorithm will be stuck in a infinite loop between right++ and right--